# Can allergies "generalize" to other substances present during an allergic reaction?

Tags: immune-system, allergy

I've heard some claims that allergic reactions to one substance can "generalize" to other substances present at the same time. For example:

- A person is allergic to lobster, but not to clams.
- The person eats lobster and clams together, and has an anaphylactic reaction to the lobster.
- Because the clams were in their system while they were having the reaction, they are now more likely to have an anaphylactic reaction to clams alone.

In searching for information about this, I'm mostly finding descriptions of cross-reactivity, meaning that people who are allergic to one substance may also have an allergic reaction to other, closely related substances. But this isn't necessarily caused by being exposed to the two substances at the same time. **Is simultaneous exposure to an allergen and a non-allergen known to increase the risk of cross-reactivity, or development of new allergies?**

Comment: Cross reactions happen most often between two molecules that are very similar, but that doesn't quite answer the question.